# django form drop-down choices are displayed "objects" instead of string representation of the model __str__

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

In my django form I am using a method to filter the drop down options to the ones that are related to the logged-in user. After the implementation the displayed values changed to `objects` rather than the `__str__` value. I am posting the simplified codes and a snapshot that shows this. I have followed everything needed, but I cannot figure out why this is happening:

**models.py**

```
class Business(models.Model):
    client=models.ForeignKey('Client',on_delete=models.CASCADE, limit_choices_to={'is_active':True},)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=False, unique=True,)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class MMRequestAttributes(models.Model):
    client=models.ForeignKey('Client',on_delete=models.CASCADE, limit_choices_to={'is_active':True},)    
    business=models.ForeignKey('Business', on_delete=models.CASCADE,limit_choices_to={'is_active':True},)

class Ticket(MMRequestAttributes):    
    no=models.CharField('Ticket Number',max_length=50,default=uuid.uuid4,null=False, blank=False, editable=False, unique=True)
    subject=models.CharField('Subject',max_length=100,null=False, blank=False)
    description=models.TextField('Description',max_length=500,null=True,blank=True)
    created_at=models.DateTimeField('Created at',auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    updated_at=models.DateTimeField('Updated at',auto_now=True, editable=False)
    created_by= models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)

    status=StateField(editable=False) 

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Ticket #' + str(self.pk)
```

**views.py**

```
def new_ticket(request):
    form=NewTicket(request.user)
    return render(request,'mmrapp/new_ticket.html',{'form':form})
```

**admin.py**

```
class UserExtend(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False,null=False,)
    client=models.ForeignKey('Client', on_delete=models.CASCADE,limit_choices_to={'is_active': True},)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Ticket, Business
from .admin import UserExtend
from django.forms import ModelChoiceField

class NewTicket(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self,user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(NewTicket, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        try:
            client_id = UserExtend.objects.values_list('client_id', flat=True).get(user=user)
            self.fields['business'].queryset=Business.objects.filter(client__id=client_id)

        except UserExtend.DoesNotExist:
            ### there is not userextend corresponding to this user, do what you want 
            pass

    class Meta:
        model=Ticket
        fields = ('subject','business')
```

**new-ticket.html**

```
{% extends 'mmrapp/__l_single_column.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block main_col %}
    <h1>New Ticket</h1>
    <form method="POST" class="new-ticket">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
{% endblock main_col %}
```

[image: snapshot]

Comment: Where do you give the name var data? I assume you checked that name does hold some data?

Comment: @Mint I have used the `admin` site to give it some data so there are data and I can see it on `admin` site

Comment: Strange, the objects are clearly coming through so it's narrowed down to the str function. Have you tried hard coding a return value to see if it comes through?

Comment: @Mint yes, I have tried `return 'hello'` in `Business` model definition and it is still showing `Business object` and not `hello`, that means `__str__` is not working at all

Comment: You're using python3?

Comment: @Mint yes, I am using python 3.4

Comment: Is the __str__ function working in the admin?

Comment: @ger.s.brett yes, it works in the admin and it was working fine before I had to add the try except part in `NewTicket` form class

Comment: Waht should be shown in the dropdown in case the userextend does not exist?

Comment: Maybe the issue is that django does not know what to put into the drop down in case it goes into the except clause-

Comment: @ger.s.brett it would not happen, but in case userextend did not exist practically nothing should show up in the drop down because we need to know the logged in user is associated with which client (everything in the drop downs will be limited to the client to which the user belong to)

Comment: "Maybe the issue is that django does not know ..." let's say we say in that case we populate one item for example "Client is unknown, register first!", how should the code line would be?

Comment: I tried this in the except clause and did not change anything `self.fields['business'].queryset=Business.objects`

Comment: If you want to have that kind of complexity I woudl think you should walk away from the model form.

Comment: right now the only thing that I am thinking about is to override the __str__ in the form model, but I have no idea how to do that

Answer (score 1):

I added this method to the model in question:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.whatever_prop_suits_your_needs
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the problem. Somehow django cannot load the original models' string representation of their objects (`__str__`) when showing them as choices in the drop downs. I had to explicitly define them again inside the from model. The attribute is called `label_from_instance`. The good thing is this way one can display them different from what they are originally defined in the models.

so the monkey patch would be:

```
self.fields['business'].label_from_instance = self.business_label

@staticmethod
def business_label(self):
    return str(self.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2.7 we were using
def **unicode**(self):
return self.name
After the python upgrade from 2.7 to 3.6 it was showing all object references in the dropdown so I added
def **str**(self):
return self.name